# how to specify constant frame rate using ffmpeg

Tags: video, ffmpeg, frame-rate

I have a video stream url that gives video frame at the rate of 1fps to 25 fps (frame rate is variable). My aim is to store this as an mp4 file with a constant frame rate of 30fps. I'm also expecting that the duration of the recorded video to be same as the duration for which I execute the ffmpeg command.

At present I use the following command

```
ffmpeg -f mjpeg -i video_stream_url \
  -vf "pad= ceil(iw/2)*2:ceil(ih/2)*2",\
       drawtext=text='%{localtime}':fontfile=/Windows/Fonts/Arial.ttf:fontcolor=white:fontsize=25:x=(W-tw)/2:y=h-(2*lh):box=1:boxcolor=0x00000000@1 \
  -c:v copy -vcodec libx264  filename.mp4
```

Present observation
The recorded video duration is almost half of the duration for which I had executed the command. To debug the problem, I have added the timestamp on the frames. When I play the recorded file, the video part of video which corresponds to low fps at source stream plays in a fast forward mode and the rest of the video (corresponding to 25 fps at source) plays normally.

How can I maintain a uniform frame rate of 30 fps throughout and ensure that recorded video file duration is same as the actual duration for which I had executed the command

Comment: What happens if you specify `-vsync vfr` (or `-vsync 2`) option as well as `-r 30` output option?

Comment: @kesh, I added the -vsync 2 and  -r 30 output options. The observations are similar to my original observations. The command was executed for 1 min, but a total of 62 frames were received during this time (1 fps). The output file is having duration of 2seconds only.
ffmpeg -f mjpeg -i video_stream_url -vf "pad= ceil(iw/2)*2:ceil(ih/2)*2",drawtext=text='%{localtime}':fontfile=/Windows/Fonts/Arial.ttf:fontcolor=white:fontsize=25:x=(W-tw)/2:y=h-(2*lh):box=1:boxcolor=0x00000000@1 -c:v copy -vcodec libx264 -vsync 2 -r 30 filename.mp4

Comment: Since total frames are 60 and ffmpeg assumes output fps as 30 based on input -r 30, then  the duration is calculated as 2 seconds ( 60 frames/ 30 fps)

Comment: You must transcode, can't do `-c:v copy`

Comment: ffmpeg -f mjpeg -i video_stream_url -vf "pad= ceil(iw/2)*2:ceil(ih/2)*2",drawtext=text='%{localtime}':fontfile=/Windows/Fonts/Arial.ttf:fontcolor=white:fontsize=25:x=(W-tw)/2:y=h-(2*lh):box=1:boxcolor=0x00000000@1 -vcodec libx264 -vsync 2 -r 30 filename.mp4

@kesh, removing the -c:v copy and specifying the -vcodec libx264 should be enough ?

Comment: Yeah (you can also remove `-c:v` altogether anything but `copy`) (please note that I'm speculatively helping you debug as I don't have firsthand experience with VFR data)

Comment: Thanks for helping @kesh, but the same behavior is observed ( 2 s video generated when the command executed for 1 min)